# The output of array is not aligned

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am taking a numpy online course, and using the same code from the video but my array output always not aligned.

My environment: Jupyter notebook 5.5.0, macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Any idea how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated m(_ _)m

My output:

[image: My output]

Video's output:

[image: Video's output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a proportional (sometimes also called "monospaced") font, i.e. a font where all characters have the same width.

Your browser's font settings have a slot for proportional fonts, but you have picked a font there that isn't actually proportional. Pick a different one.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You're a lifesaver! （＾人＾）